# hidden div text when calling many settimeouts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

The gist of it:

I'm creating an effect using jQuery where a succession of divs show up, and each div "animates" the typing of some text -- which is really just me resetting the jQuery .html() value to a text substring (of incrementally increasing length) very many times using Javascript's setTimeout().

Every once in a while the typing animation stalls partway through the text, and just hangs there until the text theoretically would have finished typing - at which point it shows the full text.  The stalls occur consistently in the same places in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari and on different computers.  The WEIRD part is that although I can see it stalling, while debugging I can still see the div text typing correctly in the DOM tree.

I also allow the user to click to skip to the next div.  The stalling issue only occurs after I've fired this click callback.

Anyone got any idea?  I'm pretty stumped here. :( Unfortunately I can't post any code, but I can give pseudocode if that would help.

Comment: Yes, please post some code, pseudo or not, to tell us what your doing.

Comment: a) are you clearing timeout (`clearTimeout(timeoutID)`) when user clicks the 'skip'? b) Try disabling your debugger while testing this - e.g. Firebug is quite heavy on CPU when things change rapidly in DOM

Answer (score 0):

Chrome, Firefox, and Safari all use JavaScript to native code compilers. These set in at unspecified points, causing a short delay in JavaScript execution. Might be the reason.